# Nomenclatura para de radio, checkbox, select, inputs, etc

Tags: html

Qual é um bom `name` para definir esses tipos de inputs?

- chk_questao1
- rdo_questao2
- txt_questao5
- slc_questao3

Qual padrão de nomenclatura é a melhor? Existe alguma como boa prática?

Comment: No servidor, tem necessidade de saber o tipo de elemento? Na minha opinião esses "chk" só atrapalham, vc terá que escrever linha por linha ao invés de ter um loop que vai de 1 até n, concatenando "questao+n". Eu utilizo somente o nome do parâmetro mesmo, `questao` está ótimo. Se for um array, basta usar `questoes[]`. Enfim, não tem resposta certa, qualquer coisa que ler aqui será baseado em opiniões.

Comment: Se por exemplo, no teu banco de dados, a coluna é `str_questao_1`, no teu _html_ o campo é `slc_questao_1`, no seu _controller_ a variável é `pst_slc_questao_1`, não vira uma bagunça ? Deixa tudo um nome só, deixe que o nome de campo (select, textarea, input) siga o mesmo nome da coluna no banco de dados. A resposta do camarada acima é boa, para uma coleção, usa array, mas não se prenda em prefixo.

Answer (score 3):

A tendência atual é não usar tais prefixos. As razões são várias

- Usar prefixos em nomes de campos, variáveis e objetos em geral vem de uma técnica ultrapassada para facilitar o entendimento do código, quando era difícil rastrear de onde vinham esses valores.
- Prefixos e sufixos desse tipo não agregam nada de útil aos nomes, pelo contrário, eles poluem o código. Além de ser mais um padrão para você decorar, eles fazem você digitar e ler esses caracteres a mais todas as vezes.
- A tendência atual é fazer o *front end* independente do *back end*. Se você atrelar os nomes dos campos ao tipo do elemento em um `<form>`, isso significa que uma mudança na tela vai obrigar uma mudança no serviço.
- Mesmo no front-end, a tendência é separar as regras de negócio e de controle da página do código HTML em si. Bibliotecas como Angular, React e muitas outras fornecem mecanismos para trabalhar com campos de forma independente. Mesmo com jQuery você consegue, em geral, trabalhar com formulários sem precisar fazer `if`s para verificar o tipo de cada campo.

Com tudo isto, não quero dize que você não deve nunca adotar algum tipo de padrão com sufixo e prefixo, mas que você deve considerar o impacto disso.

Talvez no seu projeto em específico, dado o conjunto de ferramentas e do *stack* de tecnologias que você usa, isso faça sentido. No geral, dentro do contexto das tecnologias que eu tenho conhecimento e das ferramentas que eu uso, não creio que faz.

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo utilizar os três primeiros caracteres para definir o tipo do campo e depois o resto para o campo em si, por exemplo: sel_uf, chk_ativo, edt_nome, edt_endereco... e Assim por diante.

Legal seu interesse em seguir padrões. Isso é muito bom para facilitar a manutenção do código.